# Where are savec the add-on on raspberry with openelec xbmc

Tags: raspberry-pi, xbmc

I want to edit some files in one add-on that is installed on the raspberry, so I want to access it trough ssh, but where is it?

Thanks to help me :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/storage/.xbmc/addons/
```

was the solution for me :-)

Answer (score 2):

The [wiki page for the xbmc's userdata folder](http://wiki.xbmc.org/?title=Userdata) says

> the addons themselves are not in userdata but one folder up in 'addons'

And specifies that the *default* location of the userdata folder is `/storage/.xbmc/userdata/` for OpenELEC. Therefore the addons should be in `/storage/.xbmc/addons/`.